# Haskell refactoring a do block to use (>>=) bind in simple file field count

Tags: haskell

If

```
do
    x <- y
    f x
```

is equivalent to:

```
y >>= \x -> f x
```

Then

why is this ("retrieve the number of comma separated fields on the last line of a file") :

```
λ> lline <- (last . lines) <$> readFile fname
λ> length $ split "," lline
11
```

Which if I'm doing this right, I /think/ in a do-like Prelude session I can translate like this:

```
x := lline
y := (last . lines) <$> readFile fname
f := (\lline -> length $ split "," lline)
```

Not equal to

```
λ> ((last . lines) <$> readFile fname) >>= (\lline -> (length $ split "," lline))

<interactive>:97:53-76: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO b’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the expression: (length $ split "," lline)
```

Or, my attempt at a "point-free" translation

```
λ> ((last . lines) <$> readFile fname) >>= (length $ split ",")

<interactive>:154:42-59: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘String -> IO b’
                  with actual type ‘Int’
```

?

I'd like to assign that Int to a value.  Maybe I have parentheses in the wrong place or otherwise mistranslated?

On the one hand, I see that this "works":

```
λ> ((last . lines) <$> readFile fname) >>= (\x -> putStrLn $ show $ length $ split "," x)
11
```

So I know I'm close.  This is fine for printing, but how do I assign the Int to somewhere in this translated and desugared form?

Even my intuitive, monstrous rookie ideas trying to extract that string with read:

```
λ> val = read $ ((last . lines) <$> readFile fname) >>= (\x -> length $ split "," x) :: Int
```

Are naturally failing.

Comment: ghci implicitly adds `print` to non-IO values.

Comment: Your rewriting are correct, but GHCi performs some magic. It allows `import, data, :command`, for instance, which can not occur in `do` blocks. It also has some extended defaulting rules, and when entering an expression whose type can not be made into `IO a`, it checks whether is type is in class `Show`, and prints it. So you should insert `print $ length $ ...` as GHCi automagically did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the following two are equivalent:

```
do x <- y
   f x
```

```
y >>= (\x -> f x)
```

However, in order to actually work, we have to respect `(>>=)`'s type:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

If we have a look at your expressions, we see that something's not quite right:

```
((last . lines) <$> readFile fname)    :: IO String     -- seems right
(\lline -> (length $ split "," lline)) :: String -> Int -- no IO on the right hand side!
```

Your function `length . split ","` doesn't return something in `IO`, it returns an `Int`. So you either have to use `print` or something similar to show it, or return an `IO Int` (depending on what you want to do):

```
((last . lines) <$> readLine fname) >>= print . length . split ","
```

Remember that GHCi isn't really a "normal" `do` block, otherwise simple expressions like

```
ghci> 1 + 1
2
```

would lead to type errors. Instead, GHCi checks whether the type is `IO a`. If it is, it runs the action, and if `a` is an instance of `Show`, it will also show the result:

```
ghci> data Foo = Foo -- no instance of Show
ghci> return Foo -- no output!
ghci> return (1 + 1)
2
```

If you have another expression `x` which doesn't have type `IO a`, it will act as `print x`, including `Show` instance errors:

```
ghci> Foo 

No instance for (Show Foo) arising from a use of `print'
ghci> 1 + 1
2
```

## TL;DR

Pay attention to the types and remember that GHCi has a lot of magic for convenience.